# Python remote connection to Raspberry via SSH and mosquitto

Tags: python, linux, bash, raspberry-pi

I want add remote connection feature to my Raspberry PI device.
Program was written in python 3.5.

I use mosquitto to send command from my PC to Raspberry program which listen special "command_topic"

Command:

```
./remote.exp password ssh -R 19999:localhost:22 login@ip_host
```

remote.exp code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 20
set cmd [lrange $argv 1 end]
set password [lindex $argv 0]
eval spawn $cmd
expect "assword:"
send "$password\r";
interact
```

I use class *Process* from module *multiprocessing* which runs

```
subprocess.checkout_output(command)
```

and when I run my program normally

```
"python3 main.py"
```

and then I use

```
mosquitto_pub -t "command_topic" -m "command"
```

it works. I get 19999 port on my PC but when I run my program in background

```
"nohup python3 main.py &"
```

I cannot get port and I don't know how to solve this?

Comment: Have you checked any output in nohup.out?

Comment: Noo, but I found a solution few minutes ago. Probably keyword "interact" was a problem. I changed it to "expect eof exit" like was mentioned in this link:
https://gist.github.com/nachivpn/ff2e2b8cf647af633127